# Image not visible crystal report failed to load resource status of 404 not found

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using visual studio 2013 with .net framework 4.5 
crystal report version CR4VS_13_0_14.
The problem i am facing about crystal report image. I am unable to see any image and chart in my report. I visit many URL of stack overflow and scn.sap.com regarding this problem and found many solutions. I applied many solutions but i am unable to solve my problem. I am ready to answer any of your question regrading my problem kindly help me out. here is the error image [CR Img Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnoFg.png)

I am loading my images from Mssql Database. In my db the datatype I set is "Image". I can see all the images in Visual Studio Report Viewer but when I call report from browser it shows no image in report...

Here is my report viewer aspx.cs code:

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        protected void Page_Init()
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                btn = Request.Form["btn"];
                if (btn == "btnEmployeeCard")
                {
                    url = Server.MapPath("~/" + "Reports/Employee/employeeCard.rpt");
                }
                report.Load(url);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
                CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = selectionFormula;
                CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should describe how you are loading your images, post relevant code of your aspx, cs/vb or cr code so that helpers may try to find the cause and solution. Without a look into what and how you are doing, no one can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you . Add this line to `webconfig`:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />

  <!-- Added -->
  <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GETR" verb="GET" path="Reports/CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />

  <remove name="asset" />
  <add name="asset" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
</handlers>
```